# updating columns causes data to be rendered wrong in react table library

Tags: reactjs

I need to create a table that can have 2 modes: normal and expanded. The expanded mode contains more columns.

I am trying to use [react-table-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@table-library/react-table-library) but It doesn't work properly when I change the number of columns.
It seems that the css applied to the table is not changing when switching back to normal mode.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Normal mode:

```
--data-table-library_grid-template-columns: minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr);
```

[image: normal mode]

Expanded mode:

```
--data-table-library_grid-template-columns: minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr)
```

[image: expanded mode]

Switching back to normal mode:

```
--data-table-library_grid-template-columns: minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1fr);
```

[image: bad behaviour]

This is the code:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { CompactTable } from '@table-library/react-table-library/compact';

const nodes = [
  {
    id: '0',
    name: 'Shopping List',
    deadline: new Date(2020, 1, 15),
    type: 'TASK',
    isComplete: true,
    nodes: 3,
  },
];

const NORMAL = [
  { label: 'Task', renderCell: (item) => item.name },
  {
    label: 'Deadline',
    renderCell: (item) =>
      item.deadline.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
      }),
  },
  { label: 'Type', renderCell: (item) => item.type },
];



const EXPANDED = [
  ...NORMAL,
  {
    label: 'Complete',
    renderCell: (item) => item.isComplete.toString(),
  },
  { label: 'Tasks', renderCell: (item) => item.nodes },
];



const App = () => {
  const [resize, setResize] = useState();
  const data = { nodes };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setResize(!resize)}>Resize</button>
      <CompactTable columns={resize ? EXPANDED : NORMAL} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are you changing which CSS custom property should apply? Is there a className somwhere?

Comment: I think it should render properly depending on the data provided to the columns prop.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that I need to explicitly modify this css variable:  **--data-table-library_grid-template-columns** depending on how many columns I want to display,

```
const columnsCount = 6;
getTableTheme = (columns) => {  
   return `
      --data-table-library_grid-template-columns: repeat(${columns}, minmax(0px, 1fr))
   `;
}

const theme = useTheme([
   getTheme(),
   {
      Table: getTableTheme(columnsCount),
      ...customTheme
   },
]);

return (
   <CompactTable
      theme={theme}
      ...
   />
)
```